# Can we force use to run unit test cases before pushing his code to repository

Tags: xcode, git, macos, atlassian-sourcetree

We have an iOS project and using `Source Tree` as repository.

Sometimes developers forget to run unit test cases and they are pushed in a broken state while compiling. This results in compilation failure in our Bamboo server.

Is there a way to make sure the unit test cases are properly compiling and passing?

Comment: Did you think using git hooks ?

Comment: yes we can do it with git-hooks, but I couldn't find any resource specific to it. I haven't used it before, Is it possible for you to help me more on this?

Comment: You have to know how to launch unit test using command line on your platform then return a value according to test status. There are plenty documentation on the net about command line and git hooks. You should try it yourself to implement something and give us more details of what you implement for us to help you.
Another strongly different solution is to use PIC like Jenkins for example to launch unit test as soon as developers pushed their code.